# Google IMA SDK AS3 - pauseAd

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does anyone know how to pause a VPAID flash ad using the actionscript 3 Google IMA SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version v2 does not expose vpaid functions. v3 is finished and is about to be released. It has a full set of vpaid functionality.